# Conditional formatting based on value on left cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm doing a sales sheet presentation and need to show in colours how that client did based entirely on his previous months' purchases, *green for better*, *red for worse*.

Example:

[image: How it should look]

How can I do this with conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CF crete new rule, choose `Use formula...` in rule type and
use `=C2<B2` formula for red cells and `=C2>B2` for green cells.

[image]

Comment: how can this work for cells in other collumns besides B compared to C? Are you proposing to add similar rules for each collumn?

Comment: @DenioMariz No, the formulas works according to ```Applies to``` range. The formulas are changed by CF for each cell. I.e. for ```D3``` they are ```D3<C3``` and ```D3>C3``` etc.